# SQL update inner join trouble with oracle request

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Oracle database

Hi guys, i have trouble with oracle syntax and inner join in update i tried something like this but it doesn't work

"missing SET keyword"

```sql
UPDATE table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id_description = t2.id_description  
SET field = '0.0.0.1.5.' 
WHERE t2.code='XXXX' AND t2.status IN ('VALUE1','VALUE2');
```

thx a lot

Comment: its similar but not duplicate, please help me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That works in SQL Server, In oracle there is another syntax

```
UPDATE table1 t1
  SET field = '0.0.0.1.5.'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'X'
                FROM table2 t2 
               WHERE t1.id_description = t2.id_description 
                 AND t2.code='XXXX' 
                 AND t2.status IN ('VALUE1','VALUE2'));
```

Comment: what 'X' means here ? seems to be working can i write this ?       UPDATE table1 t1
  SET field = '0.0.0.1.5.'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM table2 t2 
               WHERE t1.id_description = t2.id_description 
                 AND t2.code='XXXX' 
                 AND t2.status IN ('VALUE1','VALUE2')); is any 'cleaner' or 'smaller' solution to do this ?

Comment: Yes you can write it. 'X' here can be replaced by any valid string or number. The sub query only returns a true condition when `t1.id_description = t2.id_description` and other conditions are fulfilled.

Comment: thank you for your explaination, i keep your solution using INNER JOIN ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.field = '0.0.0.1.5.'
From table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id_description = t2.id_description  
WHERE t2.code='XXXX' AND t2.status IN ('VALUE1','VALUE2');
```

Comment: "SQL command not properly ended"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
   SET field = '0.0.0.1.5.' 
 WHERE t1.id_description in (
         select t2.id_description 
           from table2 t2
          where t2.code='XXXX' 
            AND t2.status IN ('VALUE1','VALUE2')
       )
```

Comment: does not work "missing SET keyword"

Comment: "missing right parenthesis"

Comment: cant work invalid identifier

Comment: Based on your solution, i wrote a classic simple subquery thank you:

Comment: UPDATE table1 t1
   SET field = '0.0.0.1.5.' 
 WHERE t1.id_description =
         (select t2.id_description 
           from table2 t2
          where t2.code='XXXX' 
            AND t2.status IN ('VALUE1','VALUE2')
       )

Comment: I would rather use `IN` instead of the `=` sign in the `WHERE`. The subquery can return several rows and this update will fail.